# C++ constructor - error expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c++, constructor

I've got this error "expected ')' before '*' token" and i don't get why:

This is my EventController.h code

```
#ifndef EVENTCONTROLLER_H_
#define EVENTCONTROLLER_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "EventModel.h"
#include "UserModel.h"
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Observer.h"

class EventController{
public:
    EventController(EventModel *eventModel, UserModel *userModel);
    virtual ~EventController();
    void EventDoneUndone(bool& eventcurrentstate);
    void addPerson2Event(UserModel *userModel, EventModel *eventModel);
    void Update();

private:
    EventModel *eventModel;
    UserModel *userModel;
};

#endif /* EVENTCONTROLLER_H_ */
```

And this is my EventController.cpp where i get the error

```
#include "EventController.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "EventModel.h"
#include "UserModel.h"


EventController(eventModel *eventModel, userModel *userModel){ **HERE I GET THE ERROR**
    this->eventModel = eventModel;  
    this->userModel =  userModel;       

    // eventModel->attach();    
    // userModel->attach();
}

EventController::~EventController() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void eventDoneUndone(EventModel eventModel1){
    eventModel1.toggleState();
}

void addPerson2Event(UserModel userModel1, EventModel eventModel1) {
    eventModel1.setPerson2Event(userModel1);
}

void EventController::Update(){ //maniera Pull  Observer myObs

    cout << "C'è stato un Update su";

}
```

Hope you guys can help me, i've already try to figure it out looking for solution in others guys problems but i failed.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MUQA.jpg

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. Contento di vedere che sei su StackOverflow :P

Comment: In your implementation file start ctor like this `EventController::EventController`

Comment: I saw this error when I had cyclic dependency between header files. Thus, the compiler error in this case is really bad.

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean:

```
   EventController::EventController(EventModel *eventModel, UserModel *userModel)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^                       ^
```

?

Comment: Yes, it's the line where i get the error

Comment: @ClaudioRavaglia: there are major differences between the line I posted and the one you did. I even marked them with `^`

Comment: Ok i've tried this way, but now i'm getting the same error in the file EventController.h
 
<code> EventController(EventModel *eventModel, UserModel *userModel);  <code>

error: expected ')' before '*' token EventController.h

Comment: We can't help until you post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

The signature in your `.cpp` file is not the same as the one in your header.

```
EventController(EventModel *eventModel, UserModel *userModel) //Header
EventController(eventModel *eventModel, userModel *userModel) //Source
```

You're using CamelCase in your Header for `EventModel` and `UserModel` in the header, and in your source you're just writing lowercase.
Also You forgot to add `EventController::` to your constructor and other methods in your source file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want use the constructor. So code have to be like this :

```
EventController::EventController(eventModel *eventModel, userModel *userModel){
    this->eventModel = eventModel;  
    this->userModel =  userModel;       

    // eventModel->attach();    
    // userModel->attach();
}
```

Comment: Does this fix the problem where the types are referenced in camelCase instead of PascalCase?

Comment: The answer to my last comment is no.